C# ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.8 - async with Content-Disposition "attachment" still blocks UI context
I have an ASP.NET Web API method that is asynchronous that downloads a file, using content disposition "attachment". All awaitable methods are decorated with .ConfigureAwait(false) within and without.
Here is a portion of my code:
string contentType = null;
long length = 0;

using (var blobStream = await ProcessBlobStreamAsync(reqModel, (cType, len) =>
{
    contentType = cType;
    length = len;
}, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    resp.Content = new StreamContent(blobStream);
    resp.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = fileName
    };
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
    resp.Content.Headers.ContentLength = length;
    resp.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
}
return resp;

I have Javascript that opens up a new tab and downloads from my async Web API method:
const newWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
newWindow.location.href = url;

Even though it's in a different tab -- shoot, even if I download it in an iframe -- when I try to navigate elsewhere in my main ASP.NET MVC app while a file is downloading, the MVC app hangs and waits until the download completes -- even though the Web API method has long since returned a 200 response. The 200 response returns right away, and then the download begins. There is no indication in the browser's Network tab that anything further is happening.
Things I've tried or heard about:

I have read about SynchronizationContext and how maybe no matter what, ASP.NET will only let me have one executing method at a time--but that seems crazy.  I must be misunderstanding that.

I have also read that if you decorate your method with any AuthorizeAttribute's you'll force synchronous processing even if you didn't intend it -- so [for testing only] I made sure to remove all of those, but it still happens.

I've also read that this is a problem with HTTP/1.1 only and that HTTP/2 should work--but I'm using HTTP/2, and it still happens.

I have experimented with using the Javascript fetch function instead of opening a new tab, but the user experience is bad; instead of showing the download in the browser's download section, a secret quiet connection stays open in the network tab that the user can't see -- AND the UI context is still blocked.

I've also read that any IoC happening could be blocked if you have any singleton instances being injected into your class, so I made sure that each object injected into my ApiController is unique per request. UI context is still blocked.

As a sanity check, I opened up a different browser and logged in, just to make sure there wasn't some sort of resource problem happening on my server. There wasn't; I was able to log in and navigate around in a completely different browser just fine - until I tried downloading a file there, and then that browser hung too.

I tried rerouting the file download to make a GET request for a file of Content Disposition "attachment" from a totally different website; that worked fine, but that's not my website!

I've paused my debugger while the file is downloading, and Visual Studio suggests that no code is executing at the moment.

Instead of opening in a new tab, I tried to make the download open in an iframe (as mentioned above); the file downloads fine, but the UI context is still blocked.


Is this really something that there's no way around? Users with faulty connections might spend a whole hour downloading a file. Is there really no way to unblock the UI context during that time?
Unblocking the UI thread was my whole reason for using "attachment" content disposition and opening in a new tab in the first place.

There's no UI context in web applications. If you want to avoid blocking in the client JS code when calling a controller action use async/await in the browser script, eg async function getData() { const response = await fetch(url);.... Check Using the Fetch API and How to use Promises in the Mozilla Developer Network

BTW the JS you posted does not download anything. It opens a new window and tells it to navigate to a specific URL. As for the .NET code, without knowing what ProcessBlobStreamAsync one can't be sure the .NET code isn't downloading an entire blog in memory before sending the entire block to the client. When you make an HTTP request with HttpClient the call completes when the entire response is received - unless you use GetStreamAsync, or the ResponseHeadersRead option.

waits until the download completes ... There is no indication in the browser's Network tab that anything further is happening. that's exactly what you'd see if the application code downloaded an entire blob before sending it to the client. Without the relevant code we can't help. We don't even know if your using HttpWebRequest or an Azure, AWS or Google client to retrieve a blob from cloud storage.

I figured out, this actually was working correctly . . . there was code routing this to a different MVC controller that did something similar. MVC has blocking context, while WebAPI does not. Once it hit the WebAPI successfully, it started working.
